# Sodium hydroxide grade in library denaturation for NGS

Tags: molecular-biology, dna-sequencing

If the NaOH, 1N which I bought does not have the label of molecular biology grade can it be used safely for library denaturation in NGS? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The "molecular biology grade" is just a gimmick in many situations. The reagent grade NaOH is quite pure (≥98%). The usual impurities (major being Na<sub>2</sub>CO<sub>3</sub>; ~1%) are also chemically insignificant (See the Sigma-Aldrich products [1](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/sial/221465) and [2](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/sial/s5881)). For the product that you have, read the label for details. It should be more or less the same.

Just prepare your solution in MilliQ water and pass it through a 0.2µm filter.